# Adding Legends in the plot, aligned in a row

Tags: plotting, legending, style, plot-themes

How can I add the legend in a plot, INSIDE the plot (as in the figure below), but in a way that they are arranged in row and not in column?

What I have done so far:

```
Plot[{d[10, 1, 1, 2, t, 0], , , ,}, {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}, 
LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 22, FontFamily -> "Times", Black, Bold}, 
PlotStyle -> {{Darker[Blue], 
Thickness[0.004]}, {Darker[Blue]}, {Darker[Blue]}, {Darker[
Blue]}, {Darker[Blue]}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13}, AxesStyle -> Bold, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {t [sec], \[ScriptCapitalD][t]}, 
LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13}, AxesStyle -> Bold, 
FrameStyle -> {{Directive[FontColor -> Darker[Red]], 
Automatic}, {Directive[FontColor -> Darker[Red]], Automatic}}, 
PlotLabel -> \[ScriptCapitalD] == 
Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalD], 
 0] \[Theta][
  t - Subscript[t, 0]]/(1 + 
   Log["1+\[Alpha] t"] (c + Sin[\[Beta] t])), 
PlotLegends -> 
Placed[{Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalD], 0] == 0, Subscript[t, 0] == 0, 
"\[Alpha]=1", "c=2", "\[Beta]=1"}, {0.3, 0.3}]]
```

[image]

Also, every improvement you would like to tell me, just tell me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with LineLegend combined with LegendLayout -> "Row":

```
Plot[{d[10, 1, 1, 2, t, 0], , , ,}, {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 22, FontFamily -> "Times", Black, Bold}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Darker[Blue], 
    Thickness[0.004]}, {Darker[Blue]}, {Darker[Blue]}, {Darker[
     Blue]}, {Darker[Blue]}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13}, AxesStyle -> Bold, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {t[sec], \[ScriptCapitalD][t]}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13}, AxesStyle -> Bold, 
 FrameStyle -> {{Directive[FontColor -> Darker[Red]], 
    Automatic}, {Directive[FontColor -> Darker[Red]], Automatic}}, 
 PlotLabel -> \[ScriptCapitalD] == 
   Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalD], 
     0] \[Theta][
      t - Subscript[t, 0]]/(1 + 
       Log["1+\[Alpha] t"] (c + Sin[\[Beta] t])), 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalD], 0] == 0, 
     Subscript[t, 0] == 0, "\[Alpha]=1", "c=2", "\[Beta]=1"}, 
    LegendLayout -> "Row"], {0.3, 0.3}]
 ]
```

EDIT: for changing the markers, use PointLegend instead of LineLegend combined with LegendMarkers option:

```
Plot[{d[10, 1, 1, 2, t, 0], , , ,}, {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 22, FontFamily -> "Times", Black, Bold}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Darker[Blue], 
    Thickness[0.004]}, {Darker[Blue]}, {Darker[Blue]}, {Darker[
     Blue]}, {Darker[Blue]}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13}, AxesStyle -> Bold, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {t[sec], \[ScriptCapitalD][t]}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13}, AxesStyle -> Bold, 
 FrameStyle -> {{Directive[FontColor -> Darker[Red]], 
    Automatic}, {Directive[FontColor -> Darker[Red]], Automatic}}, 
 PlotLabel -> \[ScriptCapitalD] == 
   Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalD], 
     0] \[Theta][
      t - Subscript[t, 0]]/(1 + 
       Log["1+\[Alpha] t"] (c + Sin[\[Beta] t])), 
PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[PointLegend[{Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalD], 0] == 0, 
     Subscript[t, 0] == 0, "\[Alpha]=1", "c=2", "\[Beta]=1"}, 
    LegendMarkers -> {"\[FilledDiamond]", "\[FilledCircle]", 
      "\[FilledSquare]", "\[CircleTimes]"}, 
    LegendLayout -> "Row"], {0.3, 0.3}]]
```

Comment: PERFECT. Thank you so much!

Comment: Another question, if I don't bother you: is there a way to change the "bars" before the values of the constants into points, or stars or other shapes?

Comment: Sure, see edits.